# System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Must declare the scalar variable "@Referans".'

Tags: c#, dapper

I'm trying execute a stored procedure using Dapper. I'm getting an error:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Must declare the scalar variable "@Referans".'

Here is my code:

```
var dosyaDetaySql = @"exec TurkmenBeyannameDetaylar @Referans";
var dosyaDetay = conn.Query<TurkmenBeyannemeSabitleriDetay>(dosyaDetaySql, new { dosyaResult.REF }).ToList();
```

I tried  `@"exec TurkmenBeyannameDetaylar '@Referans'";` but this isn't working either. How can I change it so that the stored procedure executes successfully?

Comment: It would be helpful to share your stored procedure declaration in your question. You don't have to include the implementation, but just the declaration where it specifies the name and parameter(s) would be useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are passing the query syntax wrong. It should be like:

```
var dosyaDetaySql = "exec TurkmenBeyannameDetaylar @Referans";
var dosyaDetay = conn
     .Query<TurkmenBeyannemeSabitleriDetay>(dosyaDetaySql, new { Referans = dosyaResult.REF})
     .ToList();
```

BTW, you might have problems with DynamicParameters declared this way. Instead it is easier IMHO to write as:

```
var parameters = new DynamicParameters();
parameters.Add("@Referans", dosyaResult.REF);

var dosyaDetaySql = @"exec TurkmenBeyannameDetaylar @Referans";
var dosyaDetay = conn
    .Query<TurkmenBeyannemeSabitleriDetay>(dosyaDetaySql, parameters)
    .ToList();
```

PS: It returns that error when the parameter name is wrong too. Be sure that SP parameter name (@Referans) matches in code where parameters are added.

EDIT: The samples below were added just to explain why I added that DynamicParameters. You wouldn't need it but in some cases you might find it easier. Decide yourself.

```
void Main()
{
    var query = @"EXEC dbo.CustOrdersDetail @ID";
    var parameters = new {ID=10280};
    var result = GetResults<dynamic>(query, parameters);
    foreach (var order in result)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"{order.ProductName}, {order.UnitPrice}, {order.Discount}, {order.ExtendedPrice}");
    }

    Console.WriteLine("=====================================");
    var parameters2 = new DynamicParameters();
    //parameters2.AddDynamicParams(new {ID=10280}); // not easy for everyone to write - I don't know why I think that way
    parameters2.Add("@ID", 10280, DbType.Int32);

    var result2 = GetResults_2<dynamic>(query, parameters2);
    foreach (var order in result2)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"{order.ProductName}, {order.UnitPrice}, {order.Discount}, {order.ExtendedPrice}");
    }
}

private static IEnumerable<T> GetResults<T>(string query, object parameters = null)
{
    using (IDbConnection db = new SqlConnection(@"Server=.\SQLExpress2012;Database=Northwind;Trusted_Connection=true"))
    {
        return db.Query<T>(query, parameters);
    }
}

public static IEnumerable<T> GetResults_2<T>(string query, DynamicParameters parameters=null)
{
    using (IDbConnection db = new SqlConnection(@"Server=.\SQLExpress2012;Database=Northwind;Trusted_Connection=true"))
    {
        return db.Query<T>(query, parameters);
    }
}
```

Both have the same result:

```
Guaraná Fantástica, 3.6000, 0, 43.2000
Pâté chinois, 19.2000, 0, 384.0000
Rhönbräu Klosterbier, 6.2000, 0, 186.0000
=====================================
Guaraná Fantástica, 3.6000, 0, 43.2000
Pâté chinois, 19.2000, 0, 384.0000
Rhönbräu Klosterbier, 6.2000, 0, 186.0000
```

Comment: I don't understand why you're advocating for declaring DynamicParameters separately. What advantage does that bring?

Comment: I see your point, method can't really accept anonymous parameter in a convenient way. However, one could declare an actual type like `var parameters = new TurkmenBeyannameDetaylarParameters { Referans = dosyaResult.REF };`. And sorry, I am unable to chat. Corporate firewall blocks chat.stackoverflow.com.

Comment: @mason, I wrote too many in chat :) You didn't see. OK but DynamicParameters is already there available, without you having that TurkmenBeyannameDetaylarParameters. That one is not anonymous either. That was the reason I wrote it.

Comment: Okay, fair enough! Thanks for your clarification, it's appreciated.